# How to use loop to exclude negative int?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a program that only accepts positive int values.

The while loop I inserted successfully loops if I put in a non-int until I input a valid int.

However, I'm having trouble doing the same thing to make it only accept positive ints. When I input a non-integer it successfully asks me again, but when I put in a neg int it seems like it skips the if statement and continues on with the program. Why is this?

Any tips on how to also make it loop until I put in a positive int?

```
while(!scnr.hasNextInt()){

            System.out.print("Please enter an integer value as decimal digits: ");
            if(dmCyl < 0){
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
            }
            scnr.next();
            }

        dmCyl = scnr.nextInt();
```

I've also tried, to no avail, using a similar while loop below and outside the one for non-ints that says

```
while(dmCyl < 0){

     System.out.print("Please input positive integer: ");

     scnr.next();
}
```

Comment: Similar question have been ask one or two hours ago. is it also you? or classmate?

Comment: Maybe classmate, I couldn't find a similar question though, could you link it?

Comment: [Here  is your classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126860/when-validating-loops-how-to-make-java-recheck-a-previous-while-statement), Jacob

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine(); //take the input in string format
    boolean valid=false;
    boolean test=true;
    int testnumber=0;

    while(valid==false)
    {
        /*Check for non-integers*/
        try
        {
            testnumber=Integer.parseInt(input); //this can take any value
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex){ //to check if the input is an integer or not
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            input = sc.nextLine();
            valid=false; //still cant get out of the while loop
            test=false; //this will always be false in case of non-integers
        }
        /*Check for positive integers*/
        if(test==true)//integer has been entered
        {
            if(testnumber<0)
            {
                System.out.println("please enter a positive integer: ");
                input = sc.nextLine();
            }
            else
            {
                valid =true; //positive integer entered, get out of the while loop
            }
        }
        test=true;
    }
    System.out.println("You entered: "+testnumber);
```

This program has two parts, one that checks if the input is indeed an integer or not and once this condition is satisfied then it checks if the number is negative or not. Since you can already check if the input is an integer or not and you just want to see if the number is negative or not then you may use this:

```
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = sc.nextInt(); //take the input in string format
    while(input<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
        input=sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("you entered: "+input);
```

Hope this helps.